# Excel::Writer::XLSX - Data Label "Value From Cells" option

Tags: excel, perl, excel-2013

I'm using Excel 2013 and within "Format Data Labels" there is a "Value From Cells" option that lets me select any cells to use as labels.

I've looked at options in chart `-> add_series -> data_labels` and don't seem to see it there. So I'm wondering if there is some way I can use custom labels?

[image: Screenshot of Excel 2013]

As you can see in the image, there is a "Format Data Labels..." and when selected, you can see "Value From Cells" on the right hand side, with "Select Range..." as an option.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. Can you please [edit] your question and include a small program to create a workbook with a chart and some example data in it, so we can help you play around with it? This is called a [mcve], and makes helping you easier. Feel free to also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Could you also maybe include a screenshot of how that looks when you do it in Excel, including the dialog? It's possible that this is simply not implemented yet. I'm sure JMCNAMARA will take patches. He also passes by here once in a while. Maybe he will see your question.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to do _Value From Cells_ with Excel 2010. Must be a newer feature, or I can't find it because the German translation is something completely different.

Comment: Hi simbabque, I added an imgur link to the original post with the option in Excel 2013 to select labels. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I will edit your question for you, since you're new. This is not a forum, so you don't need to mark things as edits or updates. The question is more like a living thing, and the target group are people that will find this page later when they search for a solution on Google. We are more like a huge FAQ database. Images are best hosted directly on Stack Exchange. In fact, they cooperate with imgur. I will reupload your image for you now.

Comment: Also, to highlight and ping someone in comments, use the name with an `@` like `@simbabque` so they get a notification.

Comment: If any high reputation person comes by, may I ask you to create a new tag: excel-writer-xlsx? :)